# Angular2 or 4, Firebase Authentication Linking Issue

Tags: angular, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

Looking for guidance in Angular4 + Firebase 3.x

USE CASE:

1. Login screen with all firebase support login methods.
2. Users should be able to register first on any login methods provided, i.e. G+, FB, TWT or email & password.
3. Upon successful login via any of the method user will be redirected to another screen to provide additional info like email, phone etc.,
4. After successful registration say via G+ the user will be signed into the app.

At this stage user logs out and logs in via FB again user will be registered in Firebase and redirected to the additional info screen. If the user enters the same email id, the Firebase throws an error. When I try to link the new FB login to the G+ id I get the following error.

[image]

```
updateFBUserInfo() {
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
let userEmail = this.userInfo.email;

const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();

user.updateProfile({
  displayName: this.userInfo.displayname,
  photoURL: this.userInfo.photoURL
}).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
  user.updateEmail(userEmail).then(function() {
    console.log('Update successful.');
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('EMAIL UPDATE ERROR: ' + error);

    firebase.auth().currentUser.linkWithRedirect(provider).then(function () {
      firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
        if (result.credential) {
          this.credential = result.credential;
          var user = result.user;
        }
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('REDIRECT Error: ' + error);
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log('LINK Error :' + error);
    })
  });
}, function(error) {
  console.log('CREDENTIAL ERROR :' + error);

  // Get reference to the currently signed-in user
  var prevUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  // Sign in user with another account
  firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(this.credential).then(function(user) {
    console.log("Sign In Success", user);
    var currentUser = user;
    // Merge prevUser and currentUser accounts and data
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Sign In Error", error);
  });
});
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: EMAIL UPDATE ERROR: Error: The email address is already in use by another account.

Comment: LINK Error :Error: User can only be linked to one identity for the given provider